# Style attribute not working in MS Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

What do I need?

- I need to make all content of the email into a single A4 size Page.

CSS

> 

```
<body style="height:297mm;width:210mm;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">

----email content---      
 </body>
```

- when i try to viewsource  email css property were already there.

Problem

- when try to print from ms outlook then html content move in 2 page of which my need is 1 page.

> working css in browser

when i try to print the same content  from browser then im able to get html content in A4 size page.

can anyone suggest how to shrink all content into single a4 size page.

any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Stop looking for a reason : **mail clients are very though regarding CSS properties**.

When you write an  e-mail, almost no CSS property is accepted.

You can find **[an exhaustive list here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)**.

After having played around with it a little bit, I can tell you that the best option to send a formatted mail is to create a `table` and style this table with inline styling.

#### Good luck with that, you will need it.

Comment: i try with table also but only font-size is working.

Comment: In your link we see, that style tag in head is working for outlook, but for me it doesn't

Comment: Style tag works but only applies to the CSS properties that work (and that you can find in the same page)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write styles in `pixels`. I have a such big experience in Email markup and Microsoft Outlook really harmful.

And Im not sure that `margin: auto` will work properly in Outlook.

So, try to write for example:

```
<body style="height:500px;width:500px;">
```

Comment: thanks for the help but still content is in 2 page can you suggest the best way shrink email.

Comment: please, provide sketch or template, I can't help you without it

Comment: i again tested inn Gmail its working but its not working outlook.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution that worked for me In Ms Outlook.

```
 <div>
   <!--[if mso]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-
     microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="yourstylinghere;" 
  stroke="f" fillcolor="#556270">

     <![endif>
```

> your content

```
  <!--[if mso]>

  </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->
     </div>
```